# How to bind data on dynamically created form using ajax for dynamically adding new inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**[EDITED] my previous question closed as duplicate, but I don't think so and I write why below. If I'm wrong, please leave a couple words of explanations if you decide to do it again. I'm newbie in dev, but I read a bunch of SO questions about topic which already been asked and still don't find answer**

My goal is to create a form with input fields that can be added from View by clicking on button. I don't know how many fields a user want to add and also I need that form will be bound to List < MyModel > and when user send it'll return to action List < MyModel >.

I created sample project to show you my solution which doesn't work. Can you help me with it please?

1. MyModel

   ```
   public class MyDogModel
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Breed { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Controller

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           Session.Clear();
           return View();
       }
       [HttpPost]
       public ViewResult MyDogs (List<MyDogModel> myDogs) 
       {
           return View(myDogs);
       }
       [HttpPost]
       public PartialViewResult AddDog(List<MyDogModel> dogs)
       {
           int fieldsCount;
           if (Session["FieldsCount"] == null)
           {
               Session["FieldsCount"] = 1;
               fieldsCount = 1;
           }
           else
           {
               fieldsCount = (int)Session["FieldsCount"];
               Session["FieldsCount"] = fieldsCount++;
           }
           return PartialView(dogs);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Index

   ```
   @{
   AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions
   {
       HttpMethod = "post",
       UpdateTargetId = "MyDogsForm",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
   };
   Layout = null;
   }
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
       <title>Index</title>
       <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
       <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div> 
           @Ajax.ActionLink("Add new dog", "AddDog", options)
           <div if="MyDogsForm">
           </div>
       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
4. Here in AddDog View I'm getting null reference error in this string

**@Html.TextBoxFor(d => d[i].Breed);**  *Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in System.Web.Mvc.dll*

```
    @model List<WebApplication2.Models.MyDogModel>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm("MyDogs","Home"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)Session["FieldsCount"]; i++)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d[i].Name);
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d[i].Breed);
        }
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    }
```

What does it mean? I just want to fill my List with number of dogs which user'll want to add.

**EDIT** Thanks @stephen-muecke for suggested solution. Maybe I'm missing something. But actually I'm looking for solution, where form will created and fulfilled with some data at the server. In this answer [POST a form array without successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful) new fields added by JQuery, I'll try it if server-side form changes via ajax not possible, but it'll be more convenient for me to avoid JQuery cause I need to bind not just TextBoxes, but DropDownLists and so on with information which generated on server from database.

Comment: you added the count of the dogs but your list is empty

Comment: why you don't ask the user about how many  dogs wants to add, and  you pass it to the AddDogs(int numberOfDogs), and inside this function create a List of dogs and add number of dogs entries to the list and posted to the client again and  it will work, shall I provide sample for you?

Comment: It makes no difference if its dropdownlists or textboxes. Ajax uses javascript do saying you want to avoid javascript/jquery makes no sense and using a link (your `Ajax.ActionLink()`) makes no sense either. If you want to add and save one 'Dog' at a time, then you need a modal form in your view that uses ajax to submit the form (something along the lines of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/)) but that means your current POST method makes no sense

Comment: @HadiHassan, but it should be, isn't it? I want the user to fill the list and send it on server. Sessin["fieldsCount"] used to count how many times user create a new inputs for new dog. About "ask home many"... I think it's more information that I needed. Cause I can obtain it from counts of click "add new dog button"

Comment: @StephenMuecke , so as I got it right. It's not possible to create a partial view that would be dynamically replaced with same partial view, but with more input fields, each time when user click on button without jquery, using just Unobtrusive Ajax (yes I know technically it's created javascript and so on)? I created a simple gif with how it's gonna work. But I'm used TextBox and string arrays, not TextBoxFor. http://imgur.com/a/elGIT

Comment: P.S. thanks for the http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/

Comment: Sorry, not sure what your saying. And why do you want to use the obsolete `Ajax` methods anyway (its not even supported in the latest MVC). But I already gave you [a link to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) in your previous question that uses the `BeginCollectionItem` helper to generate a partial view which you can call using `Ajax.ActionLink()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, okay I'll trust you and try to do it your way. Maybe I just don't understand your idea completely for this moment.